# aether: how to collect all dependencies including parent

Tags: maven, maven-3, aether

There are a fair amount of questions online involving how to use Maven / Aether to download dependencies for a given artifact.

I am however stumped as to downloading the parent poms.

I have similar code found online that does

```
CollectResult result = system.collectDependencies(session, request);
```

However the result is strictly the dependencies (compile, test, provided, runtime etc..) of the given artifact.

I am trying to setup an "offline" maven repository and as such need all relevant **pom** files as well. Certain plugins set a parent pom that I need to make sure is included as part of this transitive closure.

**Additional Rationale**

I am working on developing a solution to wrap Maven applications as a [Nix](https://nixos.org/) derivation.

In order to attain hermetic/reproducible builds Nix disallows access to the internet; which means using Maven traditionally does not work.

I can instead pre-hydrate a maven repository given the known dependencies.
I am working on a project https://github.com/fzakaria/mvn2nix which turns a Maven (pom.xml) into a full list of all dependencies needed so that they can be downloaded.

Comment: I have tried to construct such a copy job, but it only works 90% of the time. It is really hard to find all the relevant artifacts. The only reliable method I know is to run the build against an online repository and copy the downloaded artifacts. Why do you want to build such an "offline" repo? Maybe, if you explain the background, we find a different solution for your problem.

Comment: I added some more rationale.
1. I was able to download plugins
2. I had to add the default set of plugins
3. I downloaded all matching poms
4. I think I will have to add every parent pom also recursively

Comment: Then why not start with an empty local repository, do the build, and then copy the local repository to your offline environment?

Comment: @JFabianMeier thanks for your feedback; I ended up going that route which you can checkout at https://github.com/fzakaria/mvn2nix -- I would have preferred to invoke Maven's resolution algorithm through a library but the Aether library is very limited in functioanlity.